# Configure web-worker with Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuex, web-worker

I just started playing around with web-workers with my vue application. I have it setup and working in a normal setup(listen and broadcast). Now, I want to experiment integrating it with Vuex.

My question is: is there a way I can integrate my web worker with vuex. What I mean by integrate is that I can access store variables directly inside web-worker.

I saw many examples of people integrating it with redux but none with vuex.

This is my workflow:

I have a pub/sub service that pushes live position data every second. I need to process this telemetry data in the web worker, parse it and update the store and do some DOM manipulation. I want this to be done on web-worker for performance optimization.

Change current workflow from:

```
Pub/Sub -> calls store action -> parse/process -> update store -> update DOM(map, display live data)
```

TO:

```
Pub/Sub -> web-worker -> parse/process -> update store -> update DOM(map, display live data)
```

Comment: Here's an article that can help you out:- https://logaretm.com/blog/2019-12-21-vuex-off-mainthread/